# How to implement an interceptor in a timer in jakarta EE9

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, interceptor, stateless-session-bean

I want to have a Stateless session bean in JAKARTA EE9 where I print "hello" on the console every 10 seconds. This is achieved by the following code.

```
@jakarta.ejb.Stateless(name = "MyTimerEJB")
public class MyTimerBean {
    @Schedule(hour ="*", minute = "*", second = "*/10")
    public void printTime() {
        System.out.println("good day");
    }
}
```

But now, I also want to add an interceptor that intercepts this on saturdays and sundays and then prints "good weekend". I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to be working. The documentation is also a little bit limited unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [EJB specs](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html), section 7.4, you will find about the [`AroundTimeout`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/interceptor/AroundTimeout.html) annotation.

In short, all you need is a normal, enabled interceptor for the bean you are interested in, with a method annotated with `@AroundTimeout`.

Having said that, I hope that the use case you describe is only an example. As a matter of fact I find it bad practice to use an interceptor to change the behavior of the program as radically as you describe. I would find it very hard to reason about the functionality of such a program. Interceptors are good to implement cross-cutting concerns (e.g. transactions, logging, authorization) that do not mess with the core logic of the intercepted code.

If I were to implement this use case I would:

- Create a CDI `SayHello` bean that can knows how to decide what message to output depending on the day (or whatever)

  - Preferably, I would implement the "clock" functionality in another bean I can mock for unit tests
- Use the scheduler only to invoke `SayHello`, nothing more

---

Since it proved to be useful, I am briefly re-iterating the main points of the [JEE tutorial on interceptors](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/interceptors002.html#GKEDM):

**WARNING: the following is a brief summary, please follow the tutorials and documentation for concrete usage**

To define an interceptor, use one of the interceptor metadata annotations: `javax.interceptor.AroundConstruct`, `javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke`, `javax.interceptor.AroundTimeout`, `javax.annotation.PostConstruct`, `javax.annotation.PreDestroy` on a method defined on a component that the container will recognize. Could be the same component as the one containing the intercepted method or a different one.

If the interceptor is in a different class, use `javax.interceptor.Interceptors` to activate it. This annotation can go to a specific method, or on an entire class, in which case all *business methods* are intercepted. Remember, interceptors do not take effect on non-business methods (private/protected ones are definitely NOT business and a common mistake). Interceptors do NOT take effect when business calling methods of `this` object, another very common mistake, beware!

Alternatively you can define an interceptor binding annotation, e.g. (from the tutorial):

```java
@InterceptorBinding // this makes it an interceptor binding annotation
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited
pubic @interface Logged { ... }
```

Now annotating a class or method with `@Logged` will activate the interceptor defined as:

```java
@Logged
@Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logInvocation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

To actually activate the interceptor you have to use the deployment descriptor (depending on whether you are using it on EJB or CDI or both) or use the `@Priority` annotation.

Comment: Yes, it is only for an example to just get it implemented and working. Thank you!

Comment: I would still prefer to implement the logic in CDI beans (and apply any required interceptors on them) and leave the scheduler as simple as possible. Good luck anyway!

Comment: If you have a better/more easy implementation idea for an interceptor, I'm happy to hear it. The logic is not important at this moment, I just have to be able to use an interceptor :)

Comment: I'm afraid that if you really need an interceptor, then `@AroundTimeout` is the only way I can think of. See [here](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/interceptors002.html#GKEDM).